# How is the fundamental theorem of calculus used in a proof about the mild representation formula for the solution to an abstract ODE that I'm reading?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let

- $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space
- $S:[0,\infty)\to E$ be a $C^0$-semigroup
- $T>0$
- $f\in C^0([0,T],E)$

Since $S$ is a $C^0$-semigroup, $$[0,\infty)\to E\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto S(t)x\tag1$$ is continuous for all $x\in E$. However, unless $S$ is even uniformly continous, this shouldn't imply the continuity of $$[0,t]\to E\;,\;\;\;s\mapsto S(t-s)f(s)\tag2$$ for all $t\in(0,T]$.

However, how is then the fundamental theorem of calculus used in equation (12.28) of the book *An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations* by *Michael Renardy* and *Robert C. Rogers*?

---

Excerpt of the mentioned book (the authors use the symbol $T$ for both the maximal time and the semigroup $S$):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think everything is okay. Because $S$ is uniformly bounded in operator norm on any finite interval $[0,T]$, then
\begin{align}
         & \|S(t-s)f(s)-S(t-s')f(s')\| \\
         &= \|\{S(t-s)-S(t-s')\}f(s)+S(t-s')\{f(s)-f(s')\}\| \\
         &\le \|\{S(t-s)-S(t-s')\}f(s)\|+M\|f(s)-f(s')\|.
\end{align}
Hence,
$$
         \lim_{s'\rightarrow s}S(t-s')f(s')=S(t-s)f(s).
$$

Comment: Do you see the reason why the authors are defining a classical solution to be in $C^0([0,T],\mathcal D(A))$ (instead of $C^0([0,T],\mathcal D(A))$)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : In the proof of the theorem, he's deriving the necessity of the integral solution. There he needs $C^1([0,T],X)\cap C^0([0,T],\mathcal{D}(A))$ to carry out the operations needed to derive the necessity of the stated form of solution. At least that's what it looks like at first glance.